# Low download speed apt-get ubuntu server 16.04.1

Tags: 16.04, server

I have the following problem: I just installed ubuntu server 16.04.1 on a virtual machine using virtualBox, everything works fine except for one detail. When I try to update the repository using sudo apt-get update the speed that shows me the indicator is absurd, it varies between 1Kb / s and 9Kb / s when it should download 2.5 Mb / s.

I tried to change the server, I tried many servers from different countries and I have low speed, I also tried to use mirrors but it did not work.

I already checked the speed by downloading a heavy file using wget and downloading normally at a reasonable speed. The problem I see is with the apt-get

Does anyone have any explanation for this or do you have any similar experience?

Thank you very much for the collaboration.